# Why in converted video the voice and video frame doesn't get synchronous even using "source frame rate"?

Tags: video-conversion, framerate

I want to convert a movie which i captured from satellite with .ts format to .AVI so that i could open it using windows media player easier _with lower CPU usage than using codecs. I use Jetaudio  Video Converter, but each time even if I use the *Source Size* for "Size" field either for width and length and *Source Frame Rate* for "Frame Rate" field, in the output video, **the frames and voices are not synchronous**!

Comment: Actually as I see, the problem is that the original .ts file has Video Bit Rate frequency of 15Mbps, while the maximum frequency available in Jetaudio is 10Mbps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, for these files with high video bit rate more than 10 Mbps, the only choice is to increase "Frame Rate" field one degree higher than what is available in the original file to fill the gap; so, i selected the maximum "Video Bitrate" available in jetaudio which was 10 Mbps, with 29.97 as "Frame Rate" while in original file this number was 25 frames/second ! 
I should add this fact that KMPlayer as another simple software does the same job with file crop, but the difference is that it crops (converts) only to .mkv, .mp4 and .avi as video formats, but you don't need to set video Bit Rate, Auido Bit Rate , etc settings, it detects it.